# Check if app is installed with javascript

Tags: javascript, native, qr-code

I'm trying to make a system where I gather information from the users coming from a QR code. And then redirect them to correct segment.
I was wondering if I - with javascript - would be able to tell if a user has certain app installed and then deep link into that one rather than a web page.?

From what I've been able to find out searching it doesn't look like it's possible other than through a native app.

Have I understood that correctly..?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the javascript Object: "navigator". Test it by typeing it in you console and check out the "plugins" attribute. All plugins are listed... if you dont find your QR plugin, you have to manipulate the App and add an GET attribute to your URL.

Comment: I was thinking the link from the QR code is just a normal link to a page where I redirect the users to where I want them based on information I gather in the client. Like OS, device etc. Also I'd like to make the check to see if the user have the app installed and redirect them there instead of web. So, if the app is installed (could be any) I redirect them there. I don't control app. Also I can't see how a GET in the url shows me if an app is installed on the client..?

Comment: that will not work if you dont want to go nativ (like phonegap)